# FULL table scan in LEFT JOIN using OR

Tags: mysql

**How can this query be optimized to avoid the full table scan described below?**

I've got a slow query that's taking approximately 15 seconds to return.

**Let's get this part out of the way - I've confirmed all indexes are there.**

When I run `EXPLAIN`, it shows that there is a FULL TABLE scan ran on the `crosswalk` table (the index for `fromQuestionCategoryJoinID` is not used, even if I attempt to force) - if I remove either of the fields and the `OR`, the index is used and query completes in milliseconds.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.externalDisplayID SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags
FROM checklist c
LEFT JOIN questionchecklistjoin qcheckj on qcheckj.checklistID = c.id
LEFT JOIN questioncategoryjoin qcatj ON qcatj.questionID = qcheckj.questionID
LEFT JOIN questioncategoryjoin qcatjsub on qcatjsub.parentQuestionID = qcatj.questionID
LEFT JOIN crosswalk cw on (cw.fromQuestionCategoryJoinID = qcatj.id OR cw.fromQuestionCategoryJoinID = qcatjsub.id)
-- index used if I remove OR, eg.: LEFT JOIN crosswalk cw on (cw.fromQuestionCategoryJoinID = qcatj.id)
LEFT JOIN questioncategoryjoin qcj1 on qcj1.id = cw.toQuestionCategoryJoinID
LEFT JOIN question tags on tags.id = qcj1.questionID
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.name, tags.externalDisplayID;
```

Comment: MySQL is very bad at optimizing `OR` conditions. Split this into two queries that you combine with `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar - I think `UNION` could work, not sure the best way to implement it though, if you could share your thoughts in an answer I'd be happy to verify and accept

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis in the OR statement.

Comment: @Nandostyle - parens made no difference

Comment: @webaholik maybe!

Comment: @Barmar try this:
LEFT JOIN crosswalk cw ON (cw.fromQuestionCategoryJoinID, cw.fromQuestionCategoryJoinID) = (qcatj.id, qcatjsub.id)

- - -  this remove the OR!

Comment: @Nandostyle, for the heck of it I tried `LEFT JOIN crosswalk cw ON (cw.fromQuestionCategoryJoinID, cw.fromQuestionCategoryJoinID) = (qcatj.id, qcatjsub.id)` - very fast, but `tags` column was empty - guessing this is because it's essentially an `AND` vs the `OR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the query into two queries for each part of the `OR`. Then combine them with `UNION`.

```
SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT externalDisplayID SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags
FROM (
    SELECT c.id, c.name, tags.externalDisplayID
    FROM checklist c
    LEFT JOIN questionchecklistjoin qcheckj on qcheckj.checklistID = c.id
    LEFT JOIN questioncategoryjoin qcatj ON qcatj.questionID = qcheckj.questionID
    LEFT JOIN crosswalk cw on cw.fromQuestionCategoryJoinID = qcatj.id
    LEFT JOIN questioncategoryjoin qcj1 on qcj1.id = cw.toQuestionCategoryJoinID
    LEFT JOIN question tags on tags.id = qcj1.questionID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.id, c.name, tags.externalDisplayID
    FROM checklist c
    LEFT JOIN questionchecklistjoin qcheckj on qcheckj.checklistID = c.id
    LEFT JOIN questioncategoryjoin qcatj ON qcatj.questionID = qcheckj.questionID
    LEFT JOIN questioncategoryjoin qcatjsub on qcatjsub.parentQuestionID = qcatj.questionID
    LEFT JOIN crosswalk cw on cw.fromQuestionCategoryJoinID = qcatjsub.id
    LEFT JOIN questioncategoryjoin qcj1 on qcj1.id = cw.toQuestionCategoryJoinID
    LEFT JOIN question tags on tags.id = qcj1.questionID
) AS x
GROUP BY x.id
ORDER BY x.name
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to include `externalDisplayID` in `ORDER BY`, because that will order by its value from a random row in the group. You could put `ORDER BY externalDisplayID` in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` arguments if that's what you want.

Comment: thanks! Query time down to half second

Comment: down to .08 second adding `WHERE` for checklist table so it's not doing a full scan, this will work great, thanks again

Comment: (I mention a couple of optimizations on Barmar's solution.)

Comment: 0.08 seconds. Now we are talking! Thanks to @webholik!

Answer (score 0):

There is a second inefficiency going on here.  I call it "explode-implode".  First a bunch of `JOINs` (potentially) expand the number of rows in an intermediate table, then `GROUP BY c.id` collapses the number of rows back to what you started with (one row of output per row of `checkpoint`).

Before trying to help with that, please answer:

- Is `LEFT` really needed?
- How many rows in each table?  (Especially in `cw`)
- Can you get rid of `DISTINCT`?

Barmar's answer can possibly be improved upon by delaying the `JOINs to` qcj1`and`tags`until after the`UNION`:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ...
               FROM first few tables
           UNION ALL
           SELECT ...
               FROM first few tables
         ) AS u
    [LEFT] JOIN qcj1
    [LEFT] JOIN tags
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...
```

Another optimization (again building on Barmar's)

```
GROUP BY x.id
ORDER BY x.name
```

-->

```
GROUP BY x.name, x.id
ORDER BY x.name, x.id
```

When the items in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are the "same", they can be done in a single action, thereby saving (at least) a sort.

`x.name, x.id` is deterministic, where as `x.name` might put two rows with the same `name` in a different order, depending (perhaps) on the phase of the moon.

These indexes may help:

```
qcheckj:  INDEX(checklistID,  questionID)
qcatj:  INDEX(questionID,  id)
qcatjsub:  INDEX(parentQuestionID,  id)
cw:  INDEX(fromQuestionCategoryJoinID,  toQuestionCategoryJoinID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights so far, to address your questions: `LEFT` is definitely needed, because there is potentially checklists with no questions or tags. Multiple questions in a checklist may have same tag, and the intent is to have a list of unique tags. Currently 26,766 rows in cw, but will grow, as well as all the tables. Overall though, it will be a small dataset (don't expect millions of rows anytime soon). Currently, there are individual indexes, instead of clustered indexes.

Comment: (terminology)  "composite indexes", meaning multi-column.  A composite index _may_ provide better performance than single-column index(es).  Only the `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered", meaning living with the data and providing the ordering of the data in its BTree.